# Deep Learning book - trying to understand Bernoulli formulas

Tags: deep-learning, probability

In the section `6.2.2.2 Sigmoid Units for Bernoulli Output Distributions` of [The Deep Learning Book](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html) there is a section: (z is defined as $z=w^Th+b$ and $\hat{y}=\sigma(z)$)

[image]

Why did they start with `yz` and how exactly did they jump from (6.22) to (6.23)?

Also in the next paragraph they return back to "The loss function for maximum learning of a Bernoulli parametrized by a sigmoid is":

[image]

In the first part we dropped dependence on x. Now x is back, but `P(y | x)` formula is the same as `P(y)`. How is this possible?

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/269575/motivating-sigmoid-output-units-in-neural-networks-starting-with-unnormalized-lo